# Python 3.5.2/Django 1.9.8 deprecation warning. What should I replace with?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My line:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^signout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
...
...
```

The warning:

```
RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got django.contrib.auth.views.logout). Pass the callable instead.
2016-08-23T14:56:28.580019+00:00 app[jobQueue.1]:   url(r'^signout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
```

What should I be replacing this line with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It wants you to give it the actual view function:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout

...
url(r'^signout/$', logout, {'next_page': '/'}),
...
```